# How to migrate similar data between two different database structures using python with sql alchemy?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy, database-migration

I have been given a task to migrate data from `SQL SERVER` to `Oracle` database. The structure of those two databases is diferent and each table has at least 20 columns and there are at least 500 tables to migrate. I need your recomendation to choose good tools for this task. My initial choice for this task is `sqlalchemy`. There structure of databases is already there and is different. I can't edit tables.

Lets see some simplified examples. Lets say that I have a tables `Person` and `PersonAdress` in `SQL Server`. It has fields like `name`, `name2`, `surname` and keeps `person_address_id` as `foreign key`, `birth_date`.

In `Oracle` database I have a model `PERSON_DATA` and `PERSON_ADDRES` where I have fields like `NAME`, `NAME2`, `SUERNAME`, DATE_OF_BIRTH`. The table`PERSON_ADRESS`keeps the`PERSON_DATA_ID`as`foreign key`.

So there are two problems:
1)Name of fieelds can be different(`birth_date` in `SQL Server` and `DATE_OF_BIRTH` in ORACLE) but represents the same concept.

2)Data that represent the same concept may be in different tables(`person_address_id` is a foreign key in table `Person` in `SQL_SERVER`  where `PERSON_ADRESS` keeps the `PERSON_DATA_ID` as `foreign key in Oracle).

I though about using from `automap_base` from `sqlalchemy.ext.automap` to query models. But i dont know it it is the best idea. This is my pseudo code snippet. Maybe It would help to show what I have tried to do so far.. Please note that this is more pseudo-code.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base


class PersonModel:
    # DO i need this model? It suppose to represent Person table in
    # SQL SERVER
    def __init__(self, name, name2, birth_date, ...):
        self.name = name
        self.name2 = name2
        ...

class PERSON_DATAModel:
    # Do I need this model? It supose to represent table in Oracle
    def __init__(self, NAME, NAME2, DATE_OF_BIRTH, ...):
        self.NAME = NAME
        self.NAME2 = NAME2

metadata = MetaData()


sql_server_engine = create_engine('..')

metadata.reflect(sql_server_engine)
BaseSQLSERVER= automap_base(metadata=metadata)
BaseSQLSERVER.prepare()
metadata.reflect(sql_server_engine, only=['Person'])

BaseSQLSERVER.prepare()
Person = BaseSQLSERVER.classes.DaneOsMain
# The same what is above for  Oracle
oracle_server_engine = create_engine('..')
# and so on..
# to get
PERSON_DATA = BaseOracle.classes.PERSON_DATA


session = Session(sql_server_engine)
query_data = sesion.query(Person)...


PersonTable = []
for data in query_data:
    e = PersonModel(**query_data.__dict__)
    PersonTable.append(e)

# I have to push data from PersonTable somehow to PERSON_DATA table
```

Do you know good paterns to solve this problem? I would like to know good deisgn patern to solve this problem and useful `python` tools for this.

Comment: Do you need to transfer the structure to Oracle, or is it already there? Because if it is, why would you care about foreign keys or any schema-related stuff - all you need is to disable all constraints at the destination, transfer all data from source to destination tables and re-enable the constraints.

Comment: The structure is already there and I can't change it.

Comment: You don't have permissions to `ALTER TABLE`? In that case you will have to build a constraint tree to ensure you're inserting the data in the correct order which might be more difficult if your foreign keys are all over the place (let alone the possibility of circular constraints) but I don't think you'll find a tool that will do that automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-time conversion it might be easier to:

1)  Create a conversion Stored Procedure in SQL Server that will output the various tables as csv flat files in the format the Oracle tables are expecting.  You can name the files as the destination table in Oracle.

2) Write a python script to loop through each file in the folder you have outputed the files in from 1.  Bulk Load each flat file into destination table from Oracle.

For 2, you will need to disable the constraints and also provide error checking in case the file fails to load.  In the script or the flat file naming convention you can include a record count for sanity checking.